# PECL UUID package : what purpose does it serve?

Tags: php, uuid, pecl

What purpose does the [PECL UUID](http://pecl.php.net/package/uuid) package serve?

It does not have any documentation. If we pass a name (string) can we get UUIDs;  if we pass UUIDs, it will it return topic names. Are there any APIs for this purpose?

Is there any alternative for creating UUIDs?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try one of these pure code implementations for the generation of Universally Unique Identifiers (UUIDs):

http://www.ajaxray.com/blog/2008/02/06/php-uuid-generator-function/
http://www.shapeshifter.se/2008/09/29/uuid-generator-for-php/

I'm not sure why you'd pass in a string into a UUID generator - and you certainly wouldn't be able to return anything useful by passing in a UUID. The ID simply serves as something that should be globally unique once generated, and can be used for those purposes where an identifier that conforms to that principle would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your time.pure code implementations have some collision probability. ajaxray link : i had gonr through it. The other link helped me in finding a new php implementation. http://jkingweb.ca/code/php/lib.uuid/ which has simple apis.

Answer (score 1):

The PECL extension *uuid* exports the function `uuid_create()` which is used like in the following script:

```
<?php
$new_uuid = uuid_create();
echo "UUID: ", $new_uuid, "\n";
?>
```

I don't know of further uses, but this module contains more than this function. Sadly, it is completely undocumented. You should instead read the documentation of `libuuid`, which is part of the `ext2utils` project.

Some PHP alternatives can be found, like, e.g.:

- [Create a GUID in PHP](http://guid.us/GUID/PHP)¹ (Windows-specific solution),
- Using the file `/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid` in the Linux process file system (Linux-specific solution):

```
<?php
$fh = fopen("file:///proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid", "r");
$uuid = rtrim(fgets($fh));
fclose ($fh);

echo "UUID: {$uuid}\n";
?>
```

¹ The terms *GUID* and *UUID* nearly mean the same.